# Texlive + Texmaker+Ubuntu missing sty

Tags: texlive, texmaker, linux

I installed Texmaker and Texlive in my Xubuntu (basically = Ubuntu).

I want to use the kbordermatrix package, but when I compile the document in Texmaker I get the following error:

! LaTeX Error: File `kbordermatrix.sty' not found.

Is that suppose to install .sty automatically by Texlive or I have to make some setup?

I'm new to Linux, just recently changed to Ubuntu from MS Windows. I stuck on this problem for a whole day now. I would very appreciate someone can help me.

Cheers
Lee

Comment: How did you install Texmaker and Texlive? Did you use apt-get install? It's been a long time since I've done latex on Linux.

Comment: TeX Live cannot install packages on-the-fly. You must install them first. Further information depends on whether you are using your distro's packages or the upstream installer.

Comment: @Ryan Hi Ryan, since I'm new to linux, I Google it and yes I use apt-get install

Comment: @cfr Hi cfr do you know is there a solution for Linux that I could install packages on-the-fly?

Comment: @user3004698 did you try my answer/did it work?

Comment: @Ryan Hi, Ryan I'm actually trying it now. I can find the path of texmf/ but I don't know how to make the sub directory of /tex/latex/commonstuff/ (tried by sudo mkdir) I'm very new to Linux. There are many staff I don't know well.

Comment: @user3004698 I'm not aware of any on-the-fly solution other than MiKTeX. For the directory: do not use `sudo`. As your normal user, do `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/kbordermatrix` and then put the `.sty` file in the new directory.

Comment: What's the existing file structure inside texmf? If you cd to that folder, and list (`ls` the contents), what's in there? The subdirectories could already exist. Looks like @cfr replied while I typed, good answer

Comment: @Ryan Specifying `-p` will create the parent directories only if they do not already exist. This is commonly used when you don't know the existing structure (e.g. in a script to run in various places or whatever). `cd` and `ls` is fine but `cd` will fail if no personal `texmf` tree exists at all.

Comment: @cfr that's a really elegant solution, I bow to your bash skills!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the .sty file is available here.

http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml

If you run `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` In terminal, it should give you path to a folder called `texmf/`.

If you put the `.sty` file in a subdirectory of that file such as `texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/` then you should be able to run `texhash [path to texmf folder]` to have latex rescan the folder.

I took the installation instructions from here:

[Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

Comment: You do not need to run `texhash` when installing into your personal `texmf` tree and doing so is pointless. That is, unless you have specified non-standard defaults for your installation. This is possible but there is no reason to think the OP has done this. By default, TeX searches the disk for your personal tree so just putting the files in place is sufficient.

Comment: @cfr he hadn't mentioned how he installed it so I included it for completenes' sake.

Comment: Well you said to put the style file in the personal `texmf` tree. So `texhash` is not necessary unless the OP has changed the defaults. (It doesn't matter whether it is a distro package or upstream - no sane packaging would change this. It is completely standard for TeX Live.)